# Product Warranty Database

Tags: data-request, legal

Is anyone aware of an open database of warranties on products?

Ideally, the database would allow the warranties on the product to be looked up by manufacturer and model number.

This would be useful for helping people to track whether their products are still under warranty.

---

I'm highly doubtful that such a database exists for all manufacturers.  If it exists for a subset of manufacturers (e.g., electronics, home appliances, automotive, etc.) that could still be useful.

Comment: [Warranty Claims](https://www.kaggle.com/c/warranty-claims/data?select=train.csv)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  That dataset focuses on fraudulent warranty claim prediction.  It includes several helpful variables (such as type of warranty work requested and claimed amount), but does not include the actual manufacturers or product numbers.

Comment: There is also a [cleaned version](https://www.kaggle.com/amanneo/df-cleancsv) of that dataset, if anyone is interested in it.  Same general features.